# Cannot install wireless driver on a dual-language system

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, drivers, unicode

I have a problem with my Wireless Network Connection. Strangely, even though my connection setup seems to be fine, I cannot connect wirelessly to my network and through a router conected via LAN I have only limited access.

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E520 (1143) which I bought in Germany without OS. I used to have Windows Vista 32-bit in Spanish (Latin American) and everything worked perfectly. I recently decided to upgrade to Windows 8 (bought in Mexico), because I got more RAM (8 GB now) and wanted a 64-bit system. The installation and customization went fine. I downloaded the necessary drivers from Lenovo's support site and installed them only as I needed them, trying to keep my system as clean as possible.

While installing my wireless driver I get this message:

[image]

I removed the driver, which was not installed completely, and updated the language settings to match. My system's display language is English UK and my language for non-Unicode programs:

[image]

However, the problem persists. Device Manager appears mixed in two languages, English and Spanish.

PS. Usually after two hours or so of using my Ethernet connection I can connect wirelessly to my network with full access.

Comment: Update: I switched my system's display language and language for non-Unicode programs to Spanish (Mexico/Latinamerica) installed Driver, error message did not appear, but problem is not solved.
...my keyboard distribution is German (Germany)...

Comment: please HEEEELP!

Comment: i have now tryed with EVERY language option in German and problem still persist...could it be that my computer doesn't have an Intel Wireless adapter as Lenovo claims? or could it be that the adapter is not WIn8-Compatible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E520 Wireless-adapter uncompatible with Windows8?](http://superuser.com/questions/586303/lenovo-thinkpad-edge-e520-wireless-adapter-uncompatible-with-windows8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to my problem.
As user Nerdwaller suggested me, I installed the Lenovo oficial drivers for a T530 released Oct. 2012 downloaded from:

http://support.lenovo.com

and got the wireless working (:

for reference, check the following post:

[Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E520 Wireless-adapter uncompatible with Windows8?](https://superuser.com/questions/586303/lenovo-thinkpad-edge-e520-wireless-adapter-uncompatible-with-windows8)

p.s. the link above takes you to a question w/o votes and this question has one...

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Your answer would be more useful if you include the essential information here and use the link for reference.

Comment: @fixer1234 done! (: