# Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E520 Wireless-adapter uncompatible with Windows8?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad Egde E520 (1143) and I have trouble using my Wireless adapter under Win8 64-Bit. On Ubuntu 12.04. 64-bit I have no trouble. The problem is that I almost always only get a limited concectivity to my network and sporadically I get a full connection.
Also my computer presents problems while installing the Bluetooth driver.

> Could it be that WIN8 64-bit and my wireless-adapter are not compatible?

Comment: What's the card you have (in Linux `lspci | grep -i net` if you need it).  I see on the [Lenovo Page](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/default.page?) that they have W8x64 available for the Intel card.  Though the w7 driver should work..  Have you tried plugging in Ethernet and doing a Windows update to see if Windows does it automagically?

Comment: Yes, I have the Windows updates..the problem seems to have become more sporadic...anyhow, here is my terminal output  
$ lspci | grep -i net
   02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
   08:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
it is not an Intel card o.O   ... sorry for the scarce formatting i'm kind of a newbie...

Comment: I have the same card in a t530, no issues on my [drivers](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?DocID=HT073832), they were released Oct-12 - the ones on your page are March this year...  Perhaps try the ones I linked?  I haven't had issues with mine that I can recall.

Comment: I don't use bluetooth for anything, so I have no real way to gauge that. Sorry!

Comment: new driver for my machine relased on march 2013 seems to have solved the issue...i'll give this a solved in one week

Comment: problem persists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as @Nerdwaller suggested, I decided to install the Lenovo oficial drivers for a T530 released Oct. 2012 downloaded from:

http://support.lenovo.com

Today, 3 weeks after the installation the problem has not appeard.
My wireless is working great!

Thank you for the hint, Nerdwaller!